Get Visual Filters in Embedded Powerbi Report
I am trying to get the filters from a visual in my embedded Power BI report using the getFilters() function, but it only retrieves the filters from the filter pane and none from the visual itself.
I called the getFilters() function on the visual from which I want to retrieve filters. I navigated from the report to the pages, and then down to the visual level to call the getFilters() but wasn't able to get the filters from the visual itself. Here's the sample code that I tried.
report.getPages().then(pages => {
    pages.forEach(page => {
        page.getVisuals().then(visuals => {
            visuals.forEach(visual => {
                visual.getFilters(pbi.models.FiltersLevel.Visual)
                .then(visualFilters => {
                    console.log('Filters for visual ' + visual.title  + ':', visualFilters);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error retrieving filters for visual ' + visual.title + ':', error);
                });
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error("Error retrieving visuals from page:", error);
        });
    });
  }).catch(error => {
      console.error("Error retrieving pages from report:", error);
  });

Hoping to get answers for this question. Thank you so much in advance!
